# Shiny custom javascript eventlistener does not listen when used with bslib

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, bslib

I have a shiny app, where I want to change the navbar classes when the user scrolls down.
This is done using custom vanilla JS which adds an eventListener (see also https://jsfiddle.net/t317akfb/ for a fully working version).

When I include the javascript in R, I see that it is found and executed (it prints the `"START"` message in the browser console), but the event listener does not work when I scroll (like it did in the jsfiddle above).

When I manually call the `document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")...` code, it works, similarly, if I add the `navbar-red` class to the navbar, it also turns red.

## MWE

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)


js <- 'let attop = true
console.log("START")

document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  console.log("SCROLL");
  
  if (window.scrollY != 0 & attop) {
  
    attop = false;
    let col = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar");
    for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      col[i].classList.add("navbar-red");
    }
    
    console.log("Not At Top");

  } else if (window.scrollY == 0) {

    attop = true;

    let col = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar");
    for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      col[i].classList.remove("navbar-red");
    }
    console.log("At Top!");

  }
});
'

ui <- page_navbar(
  theme = bs_theme() |>
    bs_add_rules("nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-red { background-color: red !important; }"),
  id = "navbar",
  title = "NAVBAR",
    
  tabPanel(
    title = "hello",
    
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
    
    h2("header"),
    div(style = "height: 200vh; background-color: lightgray;")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output, session) {})
```

### Edit - `bslib` as a potential culprit

I have replicated the app in pure shiny without `bslib` and it works

eg

```
library(shiny)

js <- 'let attop = true
console.log("START")

document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  console.log("SCROLL");
  
  if (window.scrollY != 0 & attop) {
  
    attop = false;
    let col = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar");
    for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      col[i].classList.add("navbar-red");
    }
    
    console.log("Not At Top");

  } else if (window.scrollY == 0) {

    attop = true;

    let col = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar");
    for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      col[i].classList.remove("navbar-red");
    }
    console.log("At Top!");

  }
});
'

css <- '.navbar-red { background-color: red !important; }'


ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "",
  tabPanel(
    title = "test tab",
    
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
    h2("header"),
    div(style = "height: 200vh; background-color: lightgray;")
  ),
  selected = "test tab",
  position = c("fixed-top")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There's something strange: if I open the console and I scroll, then it works.

Comment: I found that this only happens when bslib is used. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: It looks like the scroll event does not happen on `document`.

Comment: Because when I open the console and it works, the scrollbar occupies the full height.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading `bslib` to 0.5.1.9000 (currently the dev version on github) resolves the issue.

I just needed to update the css to this identifier `nav.navbar.navbar-red`.

Not sure what caused the issue though.

### Edit

When using a sidebar in the `page_navbar`, the scrolling event listener does not work.